# Special symbols are not displayed on TTY

Tags: 10.04, console

I have a console application which is displaying special symbols like

```
☢ ☍ ⌘ ✰ ⣿ ⚡ ☯ ⚑  ↺  ⤴  ⤵
```

No matter where - putty(UTF8+Use Unicode line drawing, but I guess it's not client issue), local console, SecureCRT - I can't see them. Instead just squares. Here is my shell env variables

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
TERM=xterm
```

Any idea how to make terminal to show those symbols correctly?

Update

Glyph I am interested in

```
python -c 'print u"\u22c5 \u22c5\u22c5 \u201d \u2019 \u266f \u2622 \u260d \u2318 \u2730 " \
    u"\u28ff \u26a1 \u262f \u2691 \u21ba \u2934 \u2935 \u2206 \u231a \u2240\u2207 \u2707 " \
    u"\u26a0\xa0\u25d4 \u26a1\xa0\u21af \xbf \u2a02 \u2716 \u21e3 \u21e1  \u2801 \u2809 " \
    u"\u280b \u281b \u281f \u283f \u287f \u28ff \u2639 \u2780 \u2781 \u2782 \u2783 \u2784 " \
    u"\u2785 \u2786 \u2787 \u2788 \u2789 \u25b9\xa0\u254d \u25aa \u26af \u2692 \u25cc " \
    u"\u21c5 \u21a1 \u219f \u229b \u267a ".encode("utf8")'
```

Screenshot with Ubuntu font

[image]

Screenshot with DejaVu font

[image]

Comment: Because this is a local rendering issue with PuTTY on Windows, the proper answer to your question is that (a) this is neither Ubuntu's fault, nor (b) Ubuntu’s problem.

Comment: @JeremyVisser: I never said this is Ubuntu problem. Just looking for some way to have similar rendering on Windows. Sorry, I didn't wanted to offend Ubuntu in no way ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just copied the characters from your example and echoed them in a terminal window:

[image: UTF-8 Characters test in GNOME Terminal]

I guess TTYs do not have that much character support, so it could be a font issue.

Comment: Definitely a font issue. As long as the terminal is using utf-8 charset, it will be able to handle any utf-8 characters, though if the font doesn't have a symbol for the given character, it will be displayed as a rectangle.

Comment: Actually I am using server edition, not desktop. The same problem appears when I am connecting from windows using Putty or SecureCRT. I tried all proportional fonts in Putty. Some are partially showing the symbols, but still couldn't find any font that will display all chars. Regional settings is set to English(US) on Putty side.

Comment: @Pablo Have you tried the Ubuntu font? (http://font.ubuntu.com/) As far as I know, the terminal uses Ubuntu mono.

Comment: @lgarzo: I've updated original post with screenshot. As you can see the majority of symbols are not displayed. I nailed down the issue to finding Unicode font supporting 2000-29FF unicode ranga as per Wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_fonts . So far `Everson Mono` is the closest but faaaar away from what your screenshot is. Second is `DejaVu Sans Mono` but lacking many symbols and not clear. Puzzled...

Comment: @Pablo I've tried PuTTY on Linux, it works (got the same results as in the screenshot above). However on Windows PuTTY seems to have different ideas about font encoding despite UTF-8 is selected on the Translation page. (Even the font webpage cannot display all the needed characters in a browser). If the TTFs in the zip are the same as the font in Ubuntu, I cannot put my finger on what's going wrong.

Comment: @lgarzo: same here, banging my head to the wall few days. I thought Unicode is standard among operating systems and Putty is rather mature application.

Comment: @Pablo Ok, I've got a workaround, but you might not like it. You can use Cygwin/X as an X server on the Windows PC, and start `gnome-terminal` on the remote machine displayed on the local server (Windows). It works for my desktop Ubuntu, but might not work for a server (or at least requires some research on what to install).

Comment: @lgarzo: remote machine is headless Ubuntu 10.04 server without any X... and I really don't like installing anything that big on it. The equivalent solution is to install Ubuntu Desktop on Oracle VirtualBox, then connect to my server. Which is of course ugly solution. I still believe it's possible to get such crystal font in Windows.

Comment: @Pablo I was a bit wrong about the GNOME Terminal fonts in several ways: 1) By starting `gnome-character-map` and searching for your special characters I discovered that not all characters are from the Ubuntu Mono font, rather DejaVu Sans. (It can be verified by right clicking on the character.) 2) Windows XP cannot display Braille characters, but Windows 7 can. (Your 5th character is Braille.) It works in PuTTY. 3) Your arrow characters come from TakaoPGothic. It is not a fixed width font and does not come with some of the DejaVu Mono characters you selected. They work on Windows 7.

Comment: @lgarzo: thanks for your analysis. I've updated my original post to  a) precisely mention which glyphs I am interested in and b) screenshot with DejaVu Sans. I am using Windows 7. Even my browser doesn't display Braille. It is strange that Ubuntu is trying to get characters from different fonts, unlike(I suppose?) Windows 7.

Comment: @lgarzo: I will accept your answer and post more specific question, having all these knowledge. Thanks mate

Comment: @Pablo You're welcome! I was thinking about the problem and as a workaround was going to suggest adding the missing characters to the DejaVu Sans font. On Windows 7 they should display, since the Unicode support seems to be better. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: @lgarzo: I dug more in it and found a concept called Composite Fonts. In Windows it's located in Windows -> `GlobalMonospace.CompositeFont` for monospace and describing mappings to fonts system-wide, including fallbacks. Ubuntu has different composite font mapping. I guess I can try to modify that file, but I am afraid that I will mess how Windows looks like now. Also I don't think it's possible to create and use separate ComposteFont...

Answer (score 0):

I support @lgarzo. You may try some *bigger* fonts, especially oriental ones:

```
$ aptitude install ttf-wqy-microhei
```

Answer (score 0):

> ... putty(UTF8+Use Unicode ...

Rather than using a hex escape sequence, it maybe easier to use the actual characters to test for resident fonts (if a character is missing this is an oxymoron since it will not be possible to choose it! - which means a source machine must create a file with the desired symbols in it and then display that file with the target machine).

Programmed glyph generation can also be done using character/UTF pairings of unicodes by extraction of UTF-8 or UTF-16:

```
    python -c 'print "⌘ ✰ ⣿ ⚡ ☯ ⚑ ↺ ⤴ ⤵ ∆ ⌚"'
    ⌘ ✰ ⣿ ⚡ ☯ ⚑ ↺ ⤴ ⤵ ∆ ⌚
```

```
    python -c 'print "⌘ ✰ ⣿ ⚡ ☯ ⚑ ↺ ⤴ ⤵ ∆ ⌚".decode("unicode_escape")'
    â â° â£¿ â¡ â¯ â âº â¤´ â¤µ â â
```

```
    python -c 'print "⌘ ✰ ⣿ ⚡ ☯ ⚑ ↺ ⤴ ⤵ ∆ ⌚".decode("unicode_escape")
                                                   .encode("unicode_escape")'
    \xe2\x8c\x98 \xe2\x9c\xb0 \xe2\xa3\xbf \xe2\x9a\xa1 \xe2\x98\xaf \xe2\x9a\x91
    \xe2\x86\xba \xe2\xa4\xb4 \xe2\xa4\xb5 \xe2\x88\x86 \xe2\x8c\x9a
```

```
    python -c 'print "⌘ ✰ ⣿ ⚡ ☯ ⚑ ↺ ⤴ ⤵ ∆ ⌚".decode("unicode_escape")
                                                   .encode("unicode_escape")
                                                       .decode("string_escape")'
    ⌘ ✰ ⣿ ⚡ ☯ ⚑ ↺ ⤴ ⤵ ∆ ⌚
```

```
    python
    Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:44:07) 
    [GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> u"⌘ ✰ ⣿ ⚡ ☯ ⚑ ↺ ⤴ ⤵ ∆ ⌚"
    u'\u2318 \u2730 \u28ff \u26a1 \u262f \u2691 \u21ba \u2934 \u2935 \u2206 \u231a'
```

Unicode glyphs can be rendered using UTF-8 or UTF-16
thus `Unicode U+2318` or `UTF-16: 0x2318` or `⌘` is `UTF-8: 0xE2 0x8C 0x98`

Font details for a character can be found by literally searching for it in `character map`. It is run as an icon utility or activated with the `gnome-character-map` or `gucharmap` terminal command. Press and hold the right mouse button over the character to identify the font of residence. Also, use `Show only glyphs in this font` in the `View` menu and then scroll through the font list with an arrow key to quickly find the character's font with other resident characters.

[image]

oops
previous answer below reiterates the obvious - was looking at answers rather than question

---

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo '☢ ☍ ⌘ ✰ ⣿ ⚡ ☯ ⚑  ↺  ⤴  ⤵'
☢ ☍ ⌘ ✰ ⣿ ⚡ ☯ ⚑  ↺  ⤴  ⤵
```

and

```
python -c 'print u"\xbf  \n FreeSerif\n"  \
  u"\u2019 \u201d \u219f \u21a1 \u21af \u21ba \u21c5 \u21e1 \u21e3 \n" \
  u"\u2206 \u2207 \u2240 \u229b \u22c5 \u22c5\u22c5 \u2318 \u231a \n"  \
  u"\u25aa \u25b9 \u25cc \u25d4 \n"   \
  u"\u260d \u2622 \u262f \u2639 \u266f \u267a \u2691 \u2692 \u26a0 \u26a1 \u26af \n" \
  u"\u2780 \u2781 \u2782 \u2783 \u2784 \u2785 \u2786 \u2787 \u2788 \u2789 \n"  \
  u"\u2707 \u2716 \u2730 \u2a02 \n DejaVu\n"   \
  u"\u2801 \u2809 \u280b \u281b \u281f \u283f \u287f \u28ff \n"  \
  u"\u2934 \u2935 \u254d   \n".encode("utf8")'
```

prints

```
¿  
 FreeSerif
’ ” ↟ ↡ ↯ ↺ ⇅ ⇡ ⇣ 
∆ ∇ ≀ ⊛ ⋅ ⋅⋅ ⌘ ⌚ 
▪ ▹ ◌ ◔ 
☍ ☢ ☯ ☹ ♯ ♺ ⚑ ⚒ ⚠ ⚡ ⚯ 
✇ ✖ ✰ ⨂ 
➀ ➁ ➂ ➃ ➄ ➅ ➆ ➇ ➈ ➉ 
 DejaVu
⠁ ⠉ ⠋ ⠛ ⠟ ⠿ ⡿ ⣿ 
⤴ ⤵ ╍
```

using `gnome-terminal`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ echo \$TERM = $TERM \  \$LANG = $LANG
$TERM = xterm   $LANG = en_US.UTF-8
```

and

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

note: EOT and ENQ symbols are wrong
ref:
[How can unicode symbols u+2404 ␄ EOT and u+2405 ␅ ENQ be corrected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263332/how-can-unicode-symbols-u2404-eot-and-u2405-enq-be-corrected)

```
python -c 'print u"This is ^D EOT (NB!! no ;) \u2404 and ENQ ^E \u2405 ".encode("utf8")'
This is ^D EOT (NB!! no ;) ␄ and ENQ ^E ␅
```